# General System Exception Magento 2 UTF-8 BOM

Tags: magento2, import, products, utf-8

I have been uploading products to Magento 2 for some time using import via CSV. The first chunk worked fine and the second is throwing a general system error. UTF-8 BOM is being used... very challenging and rather frustrating. I am not sure what could be causing this to run as a general error. These two chucks are from the same exact file that I had separated out. Does anyone know of any other errors that can cause a general system exception to occur? UTF-8 BOM should compensate for any special characters. This is very odd that half of an upload will not work, on the same file and the other half would.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright,

After a lot of "chunking" the csv's into smaller loads I finally tacked down the issue here. For all those who stumble across this and scratch their heads, as I have. There were two special characters found throughout various items in the meta keywords which were causing the general system exception to happen. These characters were not being overridden by the the UTF-8 BOM which are: the degrees symbol, and a degrees symbol with a backslash through it.

Furthermore. What lead me down this path was the following: In Notepadd ++ when opening the CSV into notepad I originally noticed an odd occurance with CSV's that were not working which is that it automatically defaulted to ANSI encoding, which would generally otherwise start as UTF-8. This originally led me to be able to pre-distinguish which CSV's would error out upon import. Next, of the CSVs which had this strange designation, if using your eye to comb through them in notepad ++ you will see black symbols replacing the characters in the csv that will error out. Use them as your guide.

:)